# LightSwitch related data requests optimization

Tags: sql-server, xmlhttprequest, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with a lot of foreign keys, when opening this in a screen it takes very long time to load all related data, like 10 seconds... Here's a chart from Fiddler showing loading time, not acceptable at all[image]

I'm using Eric Erhardt's [technique](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/04/08/how-do-i-display-a-chart-built-on-aggregated-data-eric-erhardt.aspx) for creating a Domain Service and load data through. My question is if I somehow can optimize these numbers? I don't understand why it has to be one request per related data, when just making a normal entity without a domain service all related data loads in one request.

Thanks

Comment: How much data are we talking about here?

Comment: It's about 10 columns of foreign keys and less than 1000 rows.

Comment: Can you provide create scripts for the tables and some sample data? I'm not able to replicate a performance issue with my own test code.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169891/lightswitch-is-slow-ado-net-entity-framework-domain-service-wcf-ria-service

Comment: It is also duplicated here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393563/lightswitch-bulk-loading-all-requests-into-one-using-a-domain-service

Comment: Not just a duplicate post, but a duplicate by the same author.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Unique Clustered Index on the  foreign key(S).**
This will defiantly optimize load, read, fetch performance of SSMS.